# A question about series and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $ \lim_m \sum_n f(n,m) = c $ and $ 0 \leq c< \infty $. Is it true that $ \lim_m \sum_n f(n,m)^k =0 $ if k >1?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very simple counterexamples. For instance, if $f(n,m)=2^{-n}$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb N^2$, then

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge 0}f(n,m)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{2^n}=\lim_{m\to\infty}2=2\;,$$

and

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge 0}f(n,m)^2=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{4^n}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac43=\frac43\;,$$

not $0$.

Comment: @user55449: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is obviously no, take for example:

$f(n,m)=1 $ if $n=1$ and $f(n,m)=0$ if $n\geq2$ then we have $\sum_n f(n,m)=1$ and forall $k>1$ $\sum_n f(n,m)^k=1\neq0$

Comment: You're welcome.